# What is the result of this query written in ruby in rails helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in rails and I have started working on a project which has a model named 'Study', and here I am unable to know the result of this query written in rails helper.

```
def available_list_of(entities, exclude: nil)
  case entities
     when :studies then Study.where('id NOT IN (?)', exclude.nil? ? [-1] : exclude.pluck(:study_id) + [-1]).list
  end
end
```

Comment: What did you want when you wrote `NOT IN -1` in sql? 
And what is the method `.list`? It is not an ActiveRecord method, looks like it's your method

Comment: It's like Study.all , Actually, it has been done this way to handle the current case in the project

Answer (score 1):

Its some pretty dense that code that can be expanded to:

```
def available_list_of(entities, exclude: nil)
  # why use a case statement if there is only one option?
  if entities == :studies
    if exclude.nil?
      Study.where('id NOT IN (?)', '-1')
    else
       Study.where('id NOT IN (?)', (exclude.pluck(:study_id) + [-1]))
    end
  end
end
```

What the actual purpose of the code is is beyond me though as it could simply be done with a scope:

```
class Study < ApplicationRecord
  def self.excluding(excluded)
    excluded.nil? ? self : self.where.not(id: excluded)
  end
end
```

And also why would your typical auto incrementing `id` column ever contain `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

When your expression works you can use the to_sql method, [check the documentation here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) this method is from ActiveRecord::Relation

As an example:

```
Incident.where(reference: "PATAPAM").to_sql
=> "SELECT `incidents`.* FROM `incidents`  WHERE `incidents`.`reference` = 'PATAPAM'"
```

Comment: Thank you, it will help me in the long run. But it's not going to work in the case mentioned because there is a local variable exclude

Answer (score 0):

I have myself found its solution.

It says that get all the records from `Study` model, where `id` is not equal to `-1` if 'exclude' is 'nil' else get the 'study_id' from the `exclude` model and append `-1` with `study_id`. And finally `list` function is a model function which will add name and id into the list